# Aggregation replacement

Tags: sql

I have to aggregate (sum) a metric and round the result to 2 decimals. If the result of rounding is 0 the expectation is not to show anything, I mean result should be null.

eg:

```
round(sum(report.QTY),2)
```

some rows of report.QTY are very low values such as 0.0005 etc, and the rounding results to 0.
How will I show the result as null.

I can think of the following,

```
case when round(sum(dl.QTY),2)=0 then null else round(sum(dl.QTY),2) end
```

which I think may not be the best way or the only way. Appreciate any help.

Comment: No, a `CASE` or an `IF` is fine here. But you're abusing the significance of `NULL` - it does not equal `0`. How will you differ 'non-existant data' from `0` then?

Comment: Replacing 0 with NULL is for the UI purposes. There is some legacy around around the UI which I cannot change now. In my case, non existant data and 0 are equal.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server supports [NULLIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx):

> NULLIF returns the first expression if the two expressions are not equal. If the expressions are equal, NULLIF returns a null value of the type of the first expression.

So you could use:

```
NULLIF(round(sum(dl.QTY),2),0)
```

I *believe* that this is supported in [most](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) [other](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions102.htm) [products](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) [also](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/functions-conditional.html).

For future reference, although SQL is meant to be a standard language, there are sufficient differences between products that it's worth tagging your question with the actual system being used.

Comment: Sorry, I should have tagged the DB vendor/product. Its Oracle and NULLIF works, thanks for your time.

Comment: @dRv: Perhaps you are not aware that you can formally [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer that worked for you. And now that you have 15+ rep points, you can [upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) answers that were helpful, too.

Answer (score 0):

yes, konerak is right, but if you still want to use CASE then intstead of what you have done... you can try out like this way... maybe

case when dl.QTY<0.01 then 0 else round(sum(dl.QTY),2) end

please keep 0 instead of null values... will be good for fetching results..

Comment: I initially kept it 0, but the folks from other modules want to it be null. I really can't help. However, thanks a lot for your time